# Caesar segmentation fault in c language

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, undefined-behavior, cs50, argv

I'm working on the second homework Caesar of CS50. It seems most of my review is correct except the last one. I cannot handle the situation of lacking `argv[1]`, which means if I only type `./caesar`, it will segmentation fault. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
bool check;

int key (int c, string v[]);

int main (int argc, string k[])
{
    key (argc, k);
    if ((check))
    {
        string p = get_string("plaintext: ");
        int n = strlen (p);
        char f[n];
        printf ("ciphertext: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha (p[i]))
            {
            if (p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                if ((p[i] + x) > 90)
                {
                f[i] = ((p[i] + x) % 91) + 65;
                printf ("%c", f[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    f[i] = ((p[i] + x) % 91);
                    printf ("%c", f[i]);
                }
            }
            else if (p[i] >= 'a' && p[i] <= 'z')
            {
                if ((p[i] + x) > 122)
                {
                f[i] = ((p[i] + x) % 123) + 97;
                printf ("%c", f[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    f[i] = ((p[i] + x) % 123);
                    printf ("%c", f[i]);
                }
            }
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("%c", p[i]);
            }
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
int key (int c, string v[])
{
    int m = strlen (v[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
    {
        if (v[1][0] == 0)
        {
            printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (v[1][i] >= 32 && v[1][i] < 48)
        {
            printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (v[1][i] >= 58 && v[1][i] <= 126)
        {
            printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (c != 2)
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int r = atoi (v[1]);
        if (r < 1)
        {
            printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            check = true;
            return r;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can catch crashes as and when they happen, and be able to locate where in your code it happens. You can then also examine the values of all involved variables.

Comment: `char f[n];` ==> `char f[n+1];` The classic not allowing space for a string terminator.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ferig What are you expecting this statement int m = strlen (v[1]); will produce when v[1] is equal to NULL?  Write a simple program that contains only one statement strlen( NULL ); and see the result.

Comment: There are also a couple of other things you need to learn, first that you should not really be using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Another nice thing to know is about [the standard character classification and manipulation functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). Also always check for valid argument counter `argc` *before* attempting to access a specific argument, for example if no arguments were provided to your program, then `k[1]` will be `NULL`. In fact, `k[argc]` is *always* `NULL` (defined in the C specification).

Comment: But the most important thing to learn is that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. A string is a sequence of character, terminated by the special null-terminator character `'\0'`. And all strings needs this special null-terminator to be considered strings. And all strings of course needs an extra character to fit it. And it's not counted by `strlen`.

Comment: `x` is not defined.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: @WeatherVane, OP is not using `f[]` as a _string_.  +1 not needed - at least not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey
> the following constraints:
>
> — The value of argc shall be nonnegative.
>
> — argv[argc] shall be a null pointer....

So when you run the program like

```
./caesar
```

without specifying command line arguments then `argc` is equal to 1 and `argv[argc]` that is `argv[1]` is equal to `NULL`.

Your program starts with calling the function `key` that in turn at once calls the standard C function `strlen` for the pointer `v[1]` that is equal to `NULL`.

```
int key (int c, string v[])
{
    int m = strlen (v[1]);
    //...
```

This call invokes undefined behavior that results in a segmentation fault as you wrote.

Before calling the function `key` you should at first check that `argc` is equal to 2, Or inside the function this if statement

```
if (c != 2)
{
    printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}
```

should b e placed before processing `v[1]`.

Also all these checks with numerous magic numbers

```
for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
{
    if (v[1][0] == 0)
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (v[1][i] >= 32 && v[1][i] < 48)
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (v[1][i] >= 58 && v[1][i] <= 126)
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

are redundant. You could call at once the function `strtol` and check its execution whether it was successful..